# Radial shape in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to make this shape with javascript or jquery:

[image]

These dots will be dynamic and some anywhere in radial circle.
And it needs to be responsive also.

Is there any plugins for this?

Comment: Doesn't look too hard to do from scratch, or use a basic 2d canvas library. Have you tried anything? If so, what?

Comment: Hey Matt, with the help of my friend I created this https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/9aLxb1tg/1/. I'm little weak in javascript, I haven't try anything with canvas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

**You are drawing many circles**

- The circles showing orbits are stroked circles around a common center.
- The circling bodies are filled circles rotated at angles around the circumference of the orbit that they are in.

**Functions: an efficient way to write reusable code!**

Instead of re-writing (repeating) code to draw your 2 types of circles, you can create reusable functions that take in variables specific to a circle and use those variables to draw your stroked or filled circles.

**The function that strokes your orbits**

The `drawOrbit` function takes in a radius and strokes a circle at that radius around the center point:

```
// cx,cy is the concentric centerpoint of your orbits -- cx,cy don't change
// radius is how far your orbit is from the centerpoint -- radius does change
function drawOrbit(radius){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.stroke();    
}
```

**The function that draws your orbital bodies (circles)**

The `circleInOrbit` function takes in a radius and strokes a circle at that radius around the center point:

- `x,y` are computed with trigonometry.
- `cx,cy` is the orbit centerpoint
- `orbits[circle.orbitIndex]` fetches the orbit object from the orbits array. Then the orbit object tells the function how far away from the centerpoint the orbit is.
- `Math.cos(angle) & Math.sin(angle)` tells the function where on the circumference of the orbit the orbiting circle is

The `drawOrbitingCircle` function looks like this:

```
// Takes in a circle object that holds the circle's orbit & rotation angle
// It draws the orbiting circle on the specified orbit at the specified angle
function drawOrbitingCircle(circle){
    var x=cx+orbits[circle.orbitIndex]*Math.cos(circle.angle);
    var y=cy+orbits[circle.orbitIndex]*Math.sin(circle.angle);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x,y,circleRadius,0,Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle='lightgray';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.strokeStyle='white';
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

**[Addition: show signed-center circle & prevent overlapping circles]**

**This function draws a blue filled circle containing your text-sign (plus):**

- Draw a blue-filled circle at the concentric point.
- Use context.fillText('+',centerX,centerY) to draw a plus sign in the center of the blue circle.

Note that you can align text to be centered horizontally & vertically with `context.textAlign = 'center'` and `context.textBaseline = 'middle'`.

```
function drawSignedCenterCircle(signCharacter){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy, 18, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle='blue';
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillStyle='white';
    ctx.font='24px verdana';
    ctx.textAlign='center';
    ctx.textBaseline='middle';
    ctx.fillText(signCharacter,cx,cy);
}
```

**This code creates orbiting circles that won't overlap.**

It works by giving each orbiting circle a unique slice of its orbit. Since each slice is unique, any circle won't overlap with any other circle in the same orbit.

```
// calculate non-overlapping placements of orbiting bodies
for(var o=0;o<orbits.length;o++){
    var count=circleCountByOrbit[o];
    var sweep=Math.PI*2/count;
    for(var c=0;c<count;c++){
        var midAngle=(sweep*c)+sweep/2;
        var randomOffset=Math.random()*0.50-1;
        var angle=midAngle+sweep*randomOffset;
        circles.push({orbitIndex:o, angle:angle});
    }
}
```

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
function reOffset(){
  var BB=canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  offsetX=BB.left;
  offsetY=BB.top;        
}
var offsetX,offsetY;
reOffset();
window.onscroll=function(e){ reOffset(); }
window.onresize=function(e){ reOffset(); }

$("#canvas").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});

var cx=cw/2;
var cy=ch/2;
var circleRadius=10;
var blueRadius=18;
var orbits=[40,80,120];
var circleCountByOrbit=[3,5,7];
var circles=[];

// calculate non-overlapping placements of orbiting bodies
for(var o=0;o<orbits.length;o++){
  var count=circleCountByOrbit[o];
  var sweep=Math.PI*2/count;
  for(var c=0;c<count;c++){
    var midAngle=(sweep*c)+sweep/2;
    var randomOffset=Math.random()*0.50-1;
    var angle=midAngle+sweep*randomOffset;
    var x=cx+orbits[o]*Math.cos(angle);
    var y=cy+orbits[o]*Math.sin(angle);
    circles.push({
      cx:x, cy:y, 
      radius:circleRadius,
      orbitIndex:o, 
      angle:angle
    });
  }
}

// draw the stroked orbits
for(var i=0;i<orbits.length;i++){
  drawOrbit(orbits[i]);
}

// draw the orbiting bodies
for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
  drawOrbitingCircle(circles[i]);
}

// draw the signedCenterCircle
drawSignedCenterCircle('+');

function drawOrbit(radius){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.stroke();    
}

function drawOrbitingCircle(circle){
  x=circle.cx;
  y=circle.cy;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x,y,circleRadius,0,Math.PI*2);
  ctx.fillStyle='lightgray';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.strokeStyle='white';
  ctx.stroke();
}

function drawSignedCenterCircle(signCharacter){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(cx,cy, blueRadius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle='blue';
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.fillStyle='white';
  ctx.font='24px verdana';
  ctx.textAlign='center';
  ctx.textBaseline='middle';
  ctx.fillText(signCharacter,cx,cy);
}

function handleMouseDown(e){
  // tell the browser we're handling this event
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  // Check if mouse is inside any orbiting circle
  for(var i=0;i<circles.length;i++){
    var c=circles[i];
    var dx=mouseX-c.cx;
    var dy=mouseY-c.cy;
    if(dx*dx+dy*dy<c.radius*c.radius){
      drawOrbitingCircle(circles[i]);
      ctx.fillStyle='red';
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
  // Check if mouse is inside any orbiting circle
  var dx=mouseX-cx;
  var dy=mouseY-cy;
  if(dx*dx+dy*dy<blueRadius*blueRadius){
    alert('You clicked in blue circle');
  }

}
```

```css
body{ background-color:white;padding:20px;}
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Click in a circle.</h4>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: This looks useful for OP, but he's stated that he's not good with JS & has never worked with canvases. Maybe explain a little what you're doing here?

Comment: @Quelklef.  Yep, will do more explanation but the family is calling me to supper.   Priorities you know!! :-)

Comment: Thank you so much markE. It's very great. Few changes I'm trying to do. The circles are overlapping. Circles shouldn't overlap. Find demo https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/ynshpye9/1/. I'm trying to add plus (+) in blue circle. Important thing is that overlapping. I was trying to this http://jsfiddle.net/tqFuy/1/ for not overlap circles. And your explanation is great.

Comment: @locateganesh. I've added to my answer showing how to draw your blue-signed center circle and how to have randomly orbiting circles that don't overlap. Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you so much @markE. Your help and explanation is great. I learnt something in canvas.

Comment: @markE. I know, I'm giving you too much trouble. But i'm trying hard to add click event on click of lightgrey circles. But I'm not able to do I'm following all the reference demos. Also I need click on blue circle. I didn't try for this. Blue circle has no variable like likegrey circle. So I'm getting no way to add event on blue circle.  https://jsfiddle.net/locateganesh/ynshpye9/4/

Comment: @locateganesh. Adding click events is fairly easy. Just save each circle's x,y position in the same object holding the circles other info. Then click-test each circle against the mouse position like in this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262654/coordinates-from-mouseclick-comparison/16264678#16264678).

Comment: @markE, After trying on every extend. I'm not able to get click event event on lightgrey circles. And also, blue circle has no variable. How to I target blue button for a click event?

Comment: @locateganesh. I've added to my answer to show how to respond to click events on circles. Cheers!